# How to drop rows with no float in both rows and columns in an excel document with python pandas

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I am editing an excel file ,i got to this point where i am trying to drop all rows without numbers .As shown below:

```
   drinks|  period| Day1|   Day2|   Day3|   Day4|   Day5|   Day6|

1   Beer1|  weekly|                     
5   Beer2|  weekly|                     
9   Beer3|  weekly| 8.0 |    6.6|    4.8|    6.9|    8.3|    8.5|

10  Beer4|  Monthly 8.0 |    6.9|    5.8|    6.7|    6.8|    6.7|

11  Beer5|  quaterly|7.3|    7.3|    7.3|    7.3|    7.3|    7.3|

13  Beer6|  weekly|                     
17  Beer7|  weekly|                     
21  Beer8|  weekly|                     
25  Beer9|  weekly|                     
29  Beer0|  weekly|          8.2|           
33  Beer1|  weekly| 6.2|                    
34  Beer2|  weekly| 6.2|     6.2|     6.2|   6.2|     6.3|    6.3|

35  Beer3|  Month | 5.4|     5.4|     5.4|   5.4|     5.4|    5.4|

37  Beer4|  weekly|                     
41  Beer5|  weekly|          8.3|     8.2|   8.2|

42  Beer6|  weekly|                          8.5|


45  Beer7|  weekly|                     
49  Beer8|  weekly|                   8.5|      
53  Beer9|  weekly|                          8.2|
```

I keep getting the wrong result.Can anyone help?

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

excel_file_1 = 'DRINKS.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_1)

df.dropna(axis=0,how='all')

print (df)
```

I am trying to drop every row except the rows with float.Note the rows with float also have strings
the expected result should be:

```
    drinks| period| Day1|   Day2|   Day3|   Day4|   Day5|   


9   Beer3|  weekly| 8.0|    6.6|    4.8|    6.9|    8.3|    
10  Beer4|  Monthly|8.0|    6.9|    5.8|    6.7|    6.8|    
11  Beer5|  quaterly|7.3|   7.3|    7.3|    7.3|    7.3|

29  Beer1|  weekly|         8.2 |                
33  Beer2|  weekly| 6.2|                             
34  Beer3|  weekly| 6.2|    6.2|    6.2|    6.2|    6.3|    
35  Beer4|  Monthly|5.4|    5.4|    5.4|    5.4|    5.4|    
41  Beer5|  weekly| 8.3|    8.2|    8.2|         
42  Beer6| weekly|                      8.5 8.5  
49  Beer8|  weekly|             8.5              
53  Beer9|  weekly|                     8.2 8.4
```

Comment: should it be `how='any'`?

Comment: Could use modulus and ~ to filter out these rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > > I finally got the required result....

```css
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
excel_file_1 = 'Beer.xlsx'
df1 = pd.read_excel(excel_file_1)
df1['Day1'].replace('','nan', inplace=True)
df1['Day2'].replace('','nan', inplace=True)
df1['Day3'].replace('','nan', inplace=True)
df1['Day4'].replace('','nan', inplace=True)
df1['Day5'].replace('','nan', inplace=True)
df1[Day6'].replace('','nan', inplace=True)


condition =df1 [(df1['Day1'] == 'nan') & (df1['Day2'] == 'nan') & (df1['Day3'] == 'nan') & (df1['Day4'] == 'nan') & (df1['Day5'] == 'nan') & (df1['Day6'] == 'nan')].index 

df1.drop(condition , inplace=True)

print(df1)
```

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
m=df.stack().str.contains('\d').any(level=0)
n=df.stack().str.contains('\w+').all(level=0)
df[m|n]
```

**Output**

```
    drink   cost    places    sold
2   beer                 2      6
3   pepsi   4.5     New Jersy   2
4   Fruit   3       Vancouver   Nan
```

Comment: close...what if there are numbers in other columns mention that we have numbers in other columns: drink cost      places
drink| cost     | places
coke |          | New york 
fanta|          | 2
beer |          |  Germany
pepsi| 4.5      | New Jersy
Fruit| 3.0      |  Vancouver

Comment: you want to remove those rows if there are numbers in other columns? in this case you want tp remove row with '2 beer'?

Comment: yes..the float are on different columns...but some rows don't have float,i want to remove the rows without float.This a sample..the original data has 319 rows with 10 columns.

Comment: this data maybe better: drink cost      places
drink cost      sold  place
0   coke         9       New York
1  fanta          Nan   Ontario
2   beer          2        Germany
3  pepsi  4.5    4       New Jersey
4  Fruit    3       Nan        Vancouver

Comment: can you update this in the question itself? it will be helpful for others who may look at this page later as well.

Comment: Much better!One last thing...can you remove all  rows with empty values and no float.Thanks!

Comment: Code updated.update you input to best match all the scenarios you want to cover.

Comment: thanks! you are really close..for  better clarification,i updated my expectation clearly...